# OpenBSD cannot set frag limit more than 6144

Tags: openbsd, pf

I am trying to :

```
 set limit frags 10000
```

and get following info:

```
 pfctl: cannot set 'frags' limit
```

When i am trying to set it on 5000 everything works fine.

Comment: Which version of OpenBSD are you running?  What is the output of the command `sysctl kern.maxclusters`?

Comment: The output is 6144 :D Thanks a lot - i have increased it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the OpenBSD 5.3 upgrade guide](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/upgrade53.html):

> pfctl(8) will abort and fail to load the rule set if the 'frags' limit in pf.conf is higher than the kern.maxclusters sysctl This is to guard against allowing a system to run out of mbuf clusters. If it is not set, the new default is 25% of kern.maxclusters.

If you increase `kern.maxclusters`, you will also raise the limit in pf for frags.